# Apache rewrite rule with proxy flag fail to work for mediawiki service

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I have a local apache httpd hosting a mediawiki service that listen to port 3300.  The service may access in my LAN via

```
http://mylan:3300/wiki/
```

I configure my internet router to add a port forwarding entry to the mylan:3300.  I may then access to the wiki via something like:

```
http://<dynamic domain>:3300/wiki/
```

Next, I have a web site that serve globally.  The web server is apache httpd too.  I add a rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/?$ http://<dynamic domain>:3300/wiki/ [P]
```

I wish to access the wiki that host on my local LAN via the proxy method but using the global internet domain namespace:

```
http://<internet domain>/wiki/
```

After execute the above URL from internet browser, I can see the wiki contents.  However, the URL shown in address bar change to

```
http://<dynamic domain>:3300/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

In order to test the proxy rewrite rule work, I try to change the rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/?$ http://www.google.com/search?q=test [P]
```

Open the URL:

http:///wiki/

lead me to google search page but the URL remain as http:///wiki/.

Any ideas why the rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/?$ http://<dynamic domain>:3300/wiki/ [P]
```

make the browser show the new URL address instead of internet domain name space:

```
http://<internet domain>/wiki/
```

A good example is:

```
RewriteRule ^/?wiki/(.*)$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$1 [P]
```

If we access the url:

```
http://<domain>/wiki/Country
```

The URL will always rewrite and shown as

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country
```

Instead, I expect it to show as

```
http://<domain>/wiki/Country
```

but the content is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country

Answer (score -1):

Probably a redirect that includes the full link. To rewrite them add something like:

```
ProxyPassReverse /wiki/ http://<dynamic domain>:3300/wiki/
```

I also notice in the Apache online documentation for [URL Rewriting Guide - Advanced topics](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html) in the section on Content Handling, sub section Dynamic Mirror has this example:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /~quux/
RewriteRule    ^hotsheet/(.*)$  http://www.tstimpreso.com/hotsheet/$1  [P]
```

Comment: I get "500 Internal Server Error" after adding the ProxyPassReverse.